# What is this white fuzz on my mango seedling?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, seedlings, mold

My mango seedling has some white fuzzy fungus-like spot on one of its leaves. What is it, and what should I do about it?

A quick google search suggests powdery mildew, but I doubt that's it as the pictures don't match 100%. However, it has been very hot and I did let him dry out too much recently (which is said to promote powdery mildew).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

PS: this is *not* the same seedling as in my previous questions [1](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/51775/whats-wrong-with-the-emerging-root-of-my-mango-seed) & [2](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/52678/what-is-this-sticky-thing-eggs-on-my-mango-seedling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is mildew too. But it is only a small spot yet, so if you remove the affected leaf you might prevent spreading it to the rest of the leaves.

Usually mildew comes with hot and humid weather. Try to get the plant on a ventilated spot.